# Apply global fonts set in scss to Material UI components in Storybook?

Tags: reactjs, sass, material-ui, storybook

I'm trying to get a local font to show up in storybook. Currently, the font is loaded through global scss and applies to any text object. However, I am unable to get the font to show up in Material UI components.

**global.scss**

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Iosevka";
  src: url("../../assets/iosevka-ss01-regular.woff2");
}
```

**GlobalStory.tsx**

```
import { createGlobalStyle } from "styled-components"

const GlobalStory = createGlobalStyle`
  body {
    font-family: Iosevka
  }
`

export default GlobalStory
```

**.storybook/config.js**

```
import React from "react"
import { addDecorator } from "@storybook/react"
import { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components"
import { theme } from "../src/utils/theme"
import "!style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader!../src/styles/global.scss"
import GlobalStory from "../src/styles/globalStory"
import {
  createMuiTheme,
  ThemeProvider as MaterialThemeProvider,
} from "@material-ui/core/styles"

const materialTheme = createMuiTheme({
  typography: {
    fontFamily: "Iosveka",
  },
})

addDecorator(storyFn => (
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <MaterialThemeProvider theme={materialTheme}>
      {storyFn()}
    </MaterialThemeProvider>
    <GlobalStory />
  </ThemeProvider>
))
```

The font shows up using text tags like `h1` but when using something like `import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button"`, the font does not show up.

How can I get the fonts that I set globally to apply to Material UI components?

Comment: Override the button styles may be an option

Comment: Buttons are not getting the font from a global style (even with regular css) unless you specify `font-family: inherit` - https://jsbin.com/honirexare/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this issue. The solution was thanks to [iampava](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/7335#issuecomment-631994613) from GitHub

This applies to Storybook 6.x (Should work for 5.x as well).

What we are going to do is to copy the font files to the internal build folder and then specify a font-family using the fonts. In my case I was using the Avenir LT Std Roman font family.

**1st.** Install `copy-webpack-plugin`:

```
npm install copy-webpack-plugin --save-dev
```

Or

```
yarn add -D copy-webpack-plugin
```

**2nd.** Add the CopyWebpackPlugin in the webpackFinal (Note the async) inside your  `.storybook/main.js` file, like:

```
const path = require("path");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  stories: ["../src/**/*.stories.mdx", "../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"],
  addons: [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app",
  ],
  webpackFinal: async (config, { configType }) => {
    // fonts
    // config.plugins.push(CopyWebpackPlugin);
    config.plugins.push(
      new CopyWebpackPlugin({
        patterns: [
          {
            from: path.resolve(__dirname, "../src/fonts"),
            to: "static/fonts",
          },
        ],
      })
    );

    return config;
  },
};
```

**3rd.** Create a `preview-head.html` next to your `main.js` in `.storybook/preview-head.html` and then place the following:

```
<style type="text/css">
  @font-face {
    font-family: "Avenir LT Std Roman";
    src: url("static/fonts/AvenirLTStd-Roman.woff2") format("woff2"),
      url("static/fonts/AvenirLTStd-Roman.woff") format("woff");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
  }
</style>
```